# Calculating Sum Column and ignoring Na

Tags: r, na, rowsum

I am trying to create a Total sum column that adds up the values of the previous columns. However I am having difficulty if there is an NA. 
If there is an NA in the row, my script will not calculate the sum.

How do I edit the following script to essentially count the NA's as 0, or just ignore them completely but still calculate the sum. I don't want to actually change the NA to 0.

```
CTDB %>% mutate(SCARED_TOTAL_CHILD = CTDB %>% rowwise() %>% 
SELECT(SCARED_BREATHE_CHILD:SCARED_SHY_CHILD) %>% rowSums()) -> CTDB
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `rowSums` has a parameter `na.rm`. So you can try `rowSums(na.rm = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add in na.rm=TRUE

i.e

```
rowSums(na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

ummm, I think the help for the function outlines how to omit NAs from the calc.... try 
`rowSums(.,na.rm=T)`